# PHP - XML to MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, xml

I am working on a PHP code that would read data from XML store it in MySQL. So far I came to point where I read data from XML file and echo it on website. Here is the code:

```
<?php

//mysql connection
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("bet_sql") or die(mysql_error());

$xml = simplexml_load_file('http://cachepricefeeds.williamhill.com/openbet_cdn?action=template&template=getHierarchyByMarketType&classId=46&marketSort=MR&filterBIR=N');

foreach ($xml->response->williamhill->class->type as $type) {
  $type_attrib = $type->attributes();
  $type_attrib['id'];
  $type_attrib['name'];
  foreach ($type->market as $event) {
    $event_attrib = $event->attributes();
    $event_attrib['id'];
    $event_attrib['name'];
    $event_attrib['date'];
    $event_attrib['url'];
    foreach ($event->participant as $participant) {
        $participant_attrib = $participant->attributes();
          $participant_attrib['name'];
          $participant_attrib['oddsDecimal'];
    }
  }

  mysql_query("INSERT INTO games (type_id, type_name, event_id, event_name, event_url, participant_name, participant_odds) 
          VALUES ($type_attrib[id], $type_attrib[name], $event_attrib[id], $event_attrib[name], $event_attrib[url], $participant_attrib[name], $participant_attrib[oddsDecimal]) ")
          or die(mysql_error());
}
?>
```

What am I doing wrong with mysql_query? I am geting this message:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Jupiler League, 134465843, Zulte-Waregem v Genk - 75 Minutes Betting, ' at line 2

Thanks for help!

Comment: Just a word of caution since I see you are messing with sports book data. If you're having issues with this type of error you must be fairly new to MySQL and should probably not be handling this data in a production environment without someone overseeing the process.

Comment: You aren't quoting the data in your query, byt you should be using PDO or MySQLi, which allow you to prepare statements.

Answer (score 1):

This is a prime example of why you should use a [prepared statement](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) to do this. Not only is it faster than running the same `INSERT` statement over and over, it would avoid the escaping problems and gets you off the obsolete `mysql_query` function.

I had to guess what datatypes were for [bind_param](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php)

```
$msyqli = new mysqli('localhost'...); //Your connection credentials here
$sql = 'INSERT INTO games (type_id, type_name, event_id, event_name, event_url, participant_name, participant_odds) 
VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)';
$prep = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
foreach ($xml->response->williamhill->class->type as $type) {
    //Truncated the other code out for example    
    $prep->bind_param('isissss', $type_attrib[id], $type_attrib[name], $event_attrib[id], 
    $event_attrib[name], $event_attrib[url], $participant_attrib[name], $participant_attrib[oddsDecimal]);
    $prep->execute();
}
```

Comment: You should give an example to make this a useful answer ^^

Comment: Could you please help me a bit more with prepared statement? How to do it in my case? If not, thanks for resources!

Comment: Added an example. It's abbreviated for the sake of demonstration

Answer (score 0):

**Problems with insert query are**

- Array keys are given without single quotes which will cause warnings
- Values are not properly escaped. it may be the main reason of syntax error.

  ```
  mysql_query("INSERT INTO games (type_id, type_name, event_id, event_name, 
  event_url, participant_name, participant_odds) 
  VALUES ($type_attrib['id'], $type_attrib['name'], $event_attrib['id'], 
  $event_attrib['name'], $event_attrib['url'], $participant_attrib['name'],
  $participant_attrib['oddsDecimal'])"
  ) or die(mysql_error());
  ```

Comment: I did not put any code, It is the same query as specified in question. It is just for reference and for supporting above 2 points.